# Return the eigenvector corresponding to the max eigenvalue of A

Tags: python, eigenvalue, eigenvector

As the title says, I must compute the eigenvector v corresponding to the max eigenvalue. I'm not sure what commands do this. Any tips?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

#x and y both 1D NumPy arrays of same length
def eigen_X(x,y):
    xa = np.mean(x)
    ya = np.mean(y)
    x_bar = x - xa
    y_bar = y - ya
    X = np.column_stack(x_bar,y_bar)
    A = X.transpose()@X
    #The rest of the code goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

[scipy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html) provides a function that calculates eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 2D, square matrix. To get the (right?) eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue, use

```
w, vl, vr = la.eig(A)
largest_eigenvector = vr[:, np.argmax(w)]
```

Replace `vr[:, np.argmax(w)]` above with `vl[np.argmax(w)]` if you're looking for the corresponding left eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with just numpy's "linalg" library. The `eig()` function can give you the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  I converted the eigenvalues from a numpy array into a list in order to use "index" here to find the position of the largest eigenvalue.  Then I picked the corresponding column from the eigenvector array.

```
>>> from numpy import linalg as LA
>>> M = ((1,-3,3), (3,-5,3), (6,-6,4))
>>> vals, vects = LA.eig(M)
>>> maxcol = list(vals).index(max(vals))
>>> eigenvect = vects[:,maxcol]
>>> print eigenvect
[-0.40824829+0.j -0.40824829+0.j -0.81649658+0.j]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need "dominant eigenvalue" you need to find the position of the largest eigenvalue, all in absolute value. Try

```
import numpy.linalg as npla
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[0.12,6.1,-5.2], [4.6,-7.8,9.3], [3.1,2.4,8.7]])
# egv, vects = npla.eig(M) 
egv = npla.eigvals(M)
print('egv dominant of M ', egv[np.argmax(np.abs(egv))])
```

You can ignore ***np.abs(egv)*** and leave ***agv*** alone for max eigenvalue

Answer (score 0):

There is a more straightforward way to do this using [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs).

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
val, vec = eigs(your_matrix, k=1, which='LM')
```